# infer xcode build output error - *** Infer needs a working compilation command to run

Tags: clang, llvm, xcodebuild, llvm-clang, facebook-infer

I am running infer on an Xcode workspace with the following command:

```
infer run --reactive -- xcodebuild -workspace WORKSPACE_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme SCEMENAME
```

the code builds successfully. but afterwards I get:

```
   Build Succeeded
   Starting translating 56 files 

*** ERROR: Failed to execute compilation command. Output:
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
*** Infer needs a working compilation command to run.
```

...MANY OF THESE...then...

```
...
*** ERROR: Failed to execute compilation command. Output:
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
*** Infer needs a working compilation command to run.
..

Nothing to compile. Try running `xcodebuild -workspace OneScream.xcworkspace -scheme OneScream clean` first.
There was nothing to analyze.
```